# ngx-admin template npm install errors

Tags: angular, npm-install, ngx-admin

I cloned the `ngx-admin` angular template from git repo at https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin and I tried to install the node modules to start working and running the project but it gives me a list of errors:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node scripts/build.js
npm ERR! Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp verb cli [
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\souilmi\\Desktop\\NG\\ngx-admin\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
npm ERR! gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library='
npm ERR! gyp verb cli ]
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.16.0 | win32 | x64
npm ERR! gyp verb command rebuild []
npm ERR! gyp verb command clean []
npm ERR! gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
npm ERR! gyp verb command configure []
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python2 Error: not found: python2
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed  python Error: not found: python
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21) {
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT'
npm ERR! gyp verb `which` failed }
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
npm ERR! gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
npm ERR! gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at callback (C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:299:20)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:183:21)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\souilmi\\Desktop\\NG\\ngx-admin\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\souilmi\Desktop\NG\ngx-admin\node_modules\node-sass
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.16.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! Build failed with error code: 1

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\souilmi\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-19T07_42_43_960Z-debug.log
```

i already some triks like installing the leatest node-sass, deleting the package-lock.json
installing the windows-build-tools.
but nothing woks,
these are my angular and node versions:

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.6
Node: 14.16.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: undefined
...
Ivy Workspace: <error>

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1102.6 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         11.2.6 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   11.2.6 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          11.2.6 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.1102.6 (cli-only)
```

please help.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately many of the used packages in this project are outdated. I needed to change or remove some dependencies to make it work nowadays.

To fix `node-sass` issue, change `"node-sass": "xx.xx.x"` to `"sass": "^1.49.0"` in the `package.json` file in the root of the project.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a common issue with that repo and there's even a [PR](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/pull/5849/commits) to change `node-sass` to `sass`. [This issue](https://github.com/akveo/ngx-admin/issues/2056) seems to have found a fix changing the node version.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder C:\Python27 and copy python.exe and python27.dll to that folder and try again

Answer (score 0):

Removing 'node-sass' and running 'npm i -f' worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I did the below steps and it worked for me.

1. Try to uninstall node-sass (**"npm uninstall node-sass"**).
2. After uninstalling, try to install the sass package using the command
   **"npm install sass --save-dev --f"**.
3. Now run the application **"ng s -o"**.